# Manipulating an image in PHP results in striped pattern

Tags: php, image

**Edit: Just ended up using Image Magick and that fixed it.**

Long story short, I'm attempting to pull some basic information about a series of schools from Wikipedia using a combination of PHP and jQuery. Part of that information is the school's emblem or logo, which is easy enough to find in the elements list.

The problem lies in trying to do some tweaking on the image in PHP. I know the image exists at the target URL (which is on a different domain, if that helps any) and that it's the one I want, but certain images come out looking like this:

[image]

This is the original image:

[image]

Others, of all file types, come out perfectly fine.

The code for that part is as follows:

```
$ext = end(explode('.', $image));

if($ext == 'png') {
    $img = imagecreatefrompng($image);
}
else if($ext == 'jpeg' || $ext == 'jpg') {
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
}
else if($ext == 'gif') {
    $img = imagecreatefromgif($image);
}
else $img = false;

if($img) {
    $raw_x = imagesx($img);
    $raw_y = imagesy($img);

    if($raw_x > $raw_y && $raw_x > 500)
    {
        $y = (500 / $raw_x) * $raw_y;
        $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor(500, $y);
        $white = imagecolorallocate($tmp_img, 255, 255, 255);
        imagefill($tmp_img, 0, 0, $white);
        imagecopyresampled($tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, 500, $y, $raw_x, $raw_y);
        $img = $tmp_img;
    }
    else if($raw_y > 500)
    {
        $x = (500 / $raw_y) * $raw_x;
        $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($x, 500);
        $white = imagecolorallocate($tmp_img, 255, 255, 255);
        imagefill($tmp_img, 0, 0, $white);
        imagecopyresampled($tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $x, 500, $raw_x, $raw_y);
        $img = $tmp_img;
    }

    if(!file_exists("../images/schools/" . $id)) mkdir("../images/schools/" . $id, 0755, true);
    imagejpeg($img, "../images/schools/" . $id . "/photo.jpg", 100);
}
```

I've been at this for a couple days and I can't figure out what's wrong, I'm hoping a fresh set of eyes might be able to see something I don't

Comment: Are the distorted images all the same file type?

Comment: Does it look correct when you don't scale it during the `imagecopyresampled`?

Comment: @relentless - Yes, they're all PNGs, and I just noticed that they have a "Grey" image mode in Photoshop, while the working PNGs are "RGB."

Comment: @Matt - Nope, imagejpeg'ing right after the imagecreate lines gives me the same issue.

Comment: Is `image magick` and option? This is just commentary I suppose but I have always had better luck `exec`ing calls to `Image Magick` in my scripts than trying to use `php` functions.

Comment: You might be having an issue with the alpha layer of the image. Have you checked out the comments on this page? http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php

Comment: @relentless - Yup, I've tried leaving those options out and setting them to both true and false; still get the same result.

Comment: @Sean, I just tried your code with the same image as above and had no problem at all - I did not have the problem on conversion to JPG - the two files are (seemingly) identical. (I pulled the image directly from the url http://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qliv.png .) I also resized the PNG to 1000x1010 to ensure it didn't involve your resize and the result was what you expected. I would look into the version of GD. (This is using GD version 2.0.34)

Comment: @chiliNUT - Yeah it is, I'd just been doing everything in native PHP because it had worked for everything else. I'll look into Image Magick though.

Comment: @KristenJukowski - I'm running 2.0.34 as well, and even linking to the imgur url doesn't work for me. My guess is there's something else at work, so I'm gonna take a swing with Image Magick and see if I can't get around it.

Comment: @chiliNUT - Image Magick worked without a single hiccup, thank you so much!

Comment: Why not downloading the image instead ?

Comment: @DavidBélanger - Because there are approximately 22,000 items I need it to pull info on haha

Comment: It will still be faster and easier !

Comment: Glad to help! I'm yet to have an automated image manipulation it couldn't handle for me.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your conditional logic around raw image size is causing you problems.  You are not handling the case where you image equal in width and height and you are not handling cases where the images are less than 500 pixels (not sure if this is intentional, but could lead to problems with HTML layout if you specify specific heights/widths for your img elements).  You should do all your math to calculate expected scaled image size up front and then do image creation/resizing in one place (not in if conditionals).

I am assuming you want to always scale your image to be either 500px in height (if image is portrait) or 500px in width if image is landscape.  You would calculate expected dimensions as follows:

```
$target_width = 500;
$target_height = 500;

if($raw_x >= $raw_y) { // set scaling factor based on x dimension
   $scaling_factor = 500.0 / $raw_x;
   $target_height = intval(500 * $scaling_factor);
} else { // set scaling factor based on y dimension
   $scaling_factor = 500.0 / $raw_y;
   $target_width = intval(500 * $scaling_factor)
}
```

And then only have one code block for setting new temp image and resizing original into it:

```
$tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($target_width, $target_height);
$white = imagecolorallocate($tmp_img, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($tmp_img, 0, 0, $white);
imagecopyresampled($tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $target_width, $target_height, $raw_x, $raw_y);
$img = $tmp_img;
```